# MVC web application Development in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates

I am newbie in ASP.net MVC. Using VS 2017,  I'm trying to develop a application in MVC but can not create empty solution at the beginning of the project, it always gives me the templete with Home, about and Contact pages. how can I get a empty solution in which I can add model, views and Controllers.

Comment: If there isn't an empty template then you can simply delete controllers and views you do not need. Just that.

Comment: If I delete those, would it effect on the structure and configuration of the project?

Comment: No, they're discovered at run-time. As you can add a new controller/view simplya writing relevant code...in the same way you can drop them simply deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Visual Studio 2017, Click File-> New -> Project

A window will open,

-at the Left side Select Visual C#-> Web

-select ASP.NET Web application (.NET Framework)

After Entering the name of the project Click Next,

[Here is the trick]

Choose Empty for template, on the same window, there will be three check-boxes [web Forms, MVC and Web API]

Make sure  that the MVC Checkbox is checked and click OK and you will have the Empty MVC project

Comment: The Second option to select the ASP.NET web application (.NET famework ) is showing under the cloud application...Should I use that?